# Javascript array - iterating through data elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

In the following Javascript (JSON) array, the following code will iterate through employees, but how can I address the 1) individual employee number, 2) tasks or 3) sites, using Javascript or jQuery/javascript?

```
$.each(mySchedule, function(i, obj) {
  console.log(obj.employees);
});
var mySchedule = 
  {
    "schedule": {
      "employees": [{
        "employee": "1000",
        "tasks": [{
          "task1": {
            "site":"McDo",
            "from":"0900",
            "to":"1000"
          }
        },
        {
          "task2": {
            "site":"McDo",
            "from":"0900",
            "to":"1000"
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        "employee": "2000",
        "tasks": [{
          "task3": {
            "site":"HJ",
            "from":"0900",
            "to":"1000"
          }
        },
        {
          "task4": {
            "site":"KFC",
            "from":"0900",
            "to":"1000"
          }
        }]
      }]
    }
  }
```

(EDIT) I optimistically hoped that something like this would work.

```
$.each(mySchedule, function(i, obj) {               
     console.log(obj.site);                     
});
```

Comment: What problem do you have ? Did you try something ?

Comment: See [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: please see other answer. User has figured out what I was asking and provided very concise answer. If I wanted the manual for javascript objects , I would google for it.

Comment: No wonder he figured it out, it's one of the most basic and most frequently asked questions in JavaScript...

Comment: yes, right up there with alert("hello world");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code currently iterates through schedule, not employee...

```
$.each(mySchedule.schedule.employees, function(i, obj) {               
     console.log(obj.tasks);  
     console.log(obj.employee);                      
});
```

You have to walk through the elements one by one to reach the data you need. For the site, you need to reach the task as is it a property from task. The task is in the property tasks of the employee and the employee is in the property employees which is in turn in schedule...

Answer (score 2):

You should modify the data structure a little bit to address the employees directly without the need to iterating through them.

A possible example is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var s = {
"schedule": {
  "employees": {
    "1000": {
        "tasks": [{
          "task1": {
            "site":"McDo",
            "from":"0900",
            "to":"1000"
          }
        },
        {
          "task2": {
            "site":"McDo",
            "from":"0900",
            "to":"1000"
          }
        }]
    },
    "2000": {
        "tasks": [{
          "task1": {
            "site":"McDo",
            "from":"0900",
            "to":"1000"
          }
        },
        {
          "task2": {
            "site":"McDo",
            "from":"0900",
            "to":"1000"
          }
        }]
    }
  }
}
}

console.log(s["schedule"]["employees"]["1000"]);
console.log(s["schedule"]["employees"]["2000"]);

</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

The OP asked how he can get a list of employees, so here it goes:

```
console.log(s["schedule"]["employees"]);
```

The above code will return the list of employees as keys and the accompanying tasks as values.

Comment: yes, that makes since! Don't I need to say : "employees": [  {   since I have many employees?

Comment: in this version, how can I get a list of employee numbers?     $.each(mySchedule.schedule, function(i, obj) {        
    console.log(obj.employees);          
   });

Comment: @Abe I have updated the answer to add that information.